# TS2345: Argument of type 'Date | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Date | undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, datepicker

I wanted to add a Date Picker to my form but i got this error
*Error: TS2345: Argument of type 'Date | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Date | undefined'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | Date | undefined'.* Can anyone help me to solve it?

```
export class Form extends React.Component<FormProps, {
  fname:   string | undefined;
  lname:    string | undefined;
  birthDate: Date | undefined;
}> {

  constructor(props: FormProps) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      fname:    undefined,
      lname:     undefined,
      birthDate:  undefined,
    };
  }
function testField(value: string | undefined | Date, set: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string | undefined>>): boolean {
  if(value === undefined) {
    set('');
    return false;
  }
  if(value === '') {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
  let [fname, setfname] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);
  let [lsname, setlname] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);
  let [birthDate, setBirthDate] = useState<Date | null>(null);

const testNext = () => {
    let success = true;
    success = testField(fname, setFname) && success;
    success = testField(lname, setlname) && success;
    success = testField(birthDate, setBirthDate) && success;
   
return (<Fragment>
    <div className="content__form">
      <div className="formcolcontainer">
        <div className="formcol">
          <Input onChange={setFname} name="Fname" error={Fname=== ''}/>
          <Input onChange={setlname} name="lname" error={lname=== ''}/>
        </div>
        <div className="formcol">
            <DatePicker
                id='BirthDate'
                selected={birthDate}
                onChange={(date) => setBirthDate(date)}
                placeholderText="Birth Date"
                />
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
</Fragment>);}
```

Comment: Why do you use null for the `useState<Date | null>(null);` ? Using undefined will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It says that, you described your date state variable as can be `null` or `date`. However, it can also be undefined type. You can update your date state to this `useState<Date|string|undefined>`.

Alternatively, you can hover over to `onChange` props of DatePicker to see the type of "date" param has. Then you update your state type accordingly.

```
  const [birthDate, setBirthDate] = useState<Date | null | undefined>(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

DatePicker doesn't want null in the 'selected' prop and your birthDate useState is null, you can leave the default value for birthDate empty. And you should use const for React Hooks.

So:

```html
const [birthDate, setBirthDate] = useState<Date>();
```